# a problem on matrix form of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find out the matrix form of the equation
$(1+t^2)x'''+\sin(t) x''+(1+t)x'+\cos(t)x=e^{-2t}\cos (t)$

---

Can someone please tell me what is the procedure of the above problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it correctly with two $x'$'s?

Comment: sorry for my mistake.I have corrected it

Comment: What is the problem? What matrix form do you want to get? set $x_1=x, x_2=x', x_3=x''$?

Answer (score 3):

Given:

$$(1+t^2)x'''+\sin(t) x''+(1+t)x'+\cos(t)x=e^{-2t}\cos (t)$$

Let: $x_1 = x, x_2 = x', x_3 = x''$.

So, we have:

- $x'_1 = x' = x_2$
- $x'_2 = x'' = x_3$
- $x'_3 = x''' = \dfrac{-\sin t x''-(1+t)x'-\cos t x + e^{-2t}\cos t}{(1+t^2)}= \dfrac{-\sin t x_3-(1+t)x_2 -\cos t x_1 + e^{-2t}\cos t}{(1+t^2)}$

In matrix form, we can write this as $X'(t) = A(t)X(t) + F(t)$, so we have:

$$X'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x'_1(t) \\ x'_2(t) \\ x'_3(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 \\ -\dfrac{\cos t}{1+t^2} & -\dfrac{(1+t)}{1+t^2} & -\dfrac{\sin t }{1+t^2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \\ x_3(t) \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \dfrac{e^{-2t} \cos t}{1+t^2} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Needs another TU!

Comment: +1 I don't like $x$ to be a dependent variable. This position is just for $y$. :D

Answer (score 0):

Set e.g. $y=(y_0,y_1,y_2)=(x,x',x'')$, then differentiate: $y'=Ay + c$. Now, find matrix $A(t)$ and vector $c(t)$ which gives equivalent system to your equation.